# I want to change font of string without using textview in android

Tags: android, string, textview

I want to change the below string font using typeface in android and i am displaying these fonts in listview.

```
private  String [] strArray ={"hello","welcome","aneesh","raja","kruhtika","ramu"};
```

using

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Kokila.ttf");
```

I am not using any textview for this but i want to change the font of the string as per my .ttf file which will ne stored in assets.

Please help me.

Comment: Where are you presenting those strings?

Comment: Agreed. A `String` does not have a font. A `TextView` or things that inherit from it use fonts. A `WebView` uses fonts. `Paint` can use fonts.

Comment: in a listview i'm displaying those strings

Answer (score 0):

Create a fonts folder inside the assets and put your fonts file inside fonts folder.
Define your Typeface like this

```
typeFaceRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/Signika-Regular.otf");
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: not like anyhow thanx i got my ans i solved it thanx