# Change font of String / ListPreference Android

Tags: android, fonts, listpreference, android-fonts

I have a ListPreference which I use to select fonts. In the ListPreference, I want to change the font of different font names. My question is related to this - [I want to change font of string without using textview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23711302/5210825) but this doesn't work for me. 
 For example (Refer to the picture below) - On the 2nd position is "Monospace". I want to change the font of it to `Monospace`.

[image: example]

The code I use for entries is -

```
String a = "Default";
String b = "Monospace";
String c = "Unique";
String d = "Architect\'s Daughter";
String e = "Dancing Script";
CharSequence[] cs = {a, b, c, d, e};
ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) findPreference("font");
listPref.setEntries(cs);
```

Any ways how I can display the fonts itself on ListPreference? 
 Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend `ListPreference` class, and override method `onCreateDialogView()` where you create your own dialog with `listview` and custom `adapter` which will handle typeface for each row. Here is [example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist/blob/master/19-Alarm/LunchList/src/apt/tutorial/TimePreference.java) of creating custom preference view